# Change the color of all cell buttons in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I created a button on the `TableViewCell`.

When the button is pressed, the color changes continuously to white and blue.

And `ViewController` has a button to change the color of all `cells`.

In `ViewController` :

```
btnAllCheckBox.onTap
{ (tap) in
    let sections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
    var rows = 0

    for i in 0..<sections {
        rows += self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
    }

    if self.btnAllCheckBox.backgroundColor == UIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF") {
        for i in 0..<rows {
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? CustListTableViewCell

            cell?.btnCheck.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#58E5E4")
        }
        self.btnAllCheckBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#58E5E4")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustListTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustListTableViewCell
    cell.btnCheck.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF")
    return cell
}
```

In `TableViewCell` :

```
btnCheck.onTap
{ (tap) in
    if self.btnCheck.backgroundColor == UIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF")
    {
        self.btnCheck.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#58E5E4")
    }
    else
    {
        if let myViewController = self.parentViewController as? CustViewController {
            myViewController.btnAllCheckBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF")
        }
        self.btnCheck.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF")
    }
}
```

List of bugs:

It's the first situation. (`Cell` count = 1000)

I have a cell that does not change color when I press the Select All button.
I tried to print the log using `print`, but there was no problem.

Second situation. (`Cell` count = 1000)

If I click on the second `cell` button and drag the screen, the selected position will change! (Common to all `Cells`)

```
ex) row 2 btnCheck.backgroundColor = #58E5E4
-> Drag Screen
-> row 2 btnCheck.backgroundColor = #FFFFFF
-> row 3,4 ... btnCheck.backgroundColor = #58E5E4
```

Third case:

If I click 3rd cell, 13, 23, ... color changes as well.

I think I implemented it without problems, but I get an error... Please help me

Comment: Don't you have a data source array ? like struct CellModel { var bgColor: UIColor }; let arrayOfData: [CellModel]; You must have it.

Comment: @jpulikkottil Thanks!! I managed to create and manage an array variable and it succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take note that `UITableViewCell` is created with `dequeueReusableCell` method, which means the cell will keep reuse the same `UITableViewCell` for each rows.

Thus, in order to make changes of UITableViewCell is to keep the changing values in viewController in variables or objects. Then in your `cellForRowAt` method will just follow the value.

Below is an example (not exactly to solve, but will help your problem).

In your viewController, add a variable to change the color.

```
var dynamicColor: UIColor = .red

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustListTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustListTableViewCell
    cell.btnCheck.backgroundColor = dynamicColor
    return cell
}
```

In your triggering method, you can make changes to that `dynamicColor` variable.

```
btnCheck.onTap
{ (tap) in
    if self.btnCheck.backgroundColor == .red
    {
        self.btnCheck.backgroundColor = .blue
        dynamicColor = .blue

    }
    else if self.btnCheck.backgroundColor == .blue
    {
        self.btnCheck.backgroundColor = .red
        dynamicColor = .red
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And dont forget to reload the tableView after each changes to reflect the rows

```
tableView.reloadData()
```